# Office 2010 Like Controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, ms-office

Anyone know what control this is or how I add it, if it can be used in WPF?

[image]

I'm referring to the menu:  File | Home | Page Layout | Mailings | etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean the Ribbon.
You are lucky, there has just been an official release from Microsoft, so you do not need any external libraries.
http://10rem.net/blog/2010/08/02/announcing-microsoft-ribbon-for-wpf-rtw

Comment: Perfect!!! Talking about getting lucky on the release date!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's called a *Ribbon Control* and there's one called [RibbonBar](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/OdysseyRibbonBar.aspx) in the Odessy Libary.

Although it's styles mimic 2007 more, you can write your own theme for the control if you want.

Comment: It would be nice if Microsoft would include some of their fancier UI controls in the standard libararies. I once put tonnes of effort trying to get tabbed documents like in VisualStudio 2008.